# About regularity of solutions of this PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, geometric-topology

Let us consider the equation in the 2d torus
$$\nabla \cdot f=g^2,$$
where $\nabla \cdot f$ denotes the divergence operator and $g^2$ has zero mean. In particular, we can see these functions as they were defined in $\mathbb{R} ^2$ and they were $2 \pi-$ periodic in each variable.

I know that this equation doesn't admit a solution $f \in W^{1,1}$ if $g \in L^2$. My question is: Is there a solution in $W^{1,1}$ for every $g^2$ in the Lorentz space $L^{2,1}$? If this is not possible, What is the best regularity that we can expect for the solution given $g$ under this condition?

Comment: Perhaps [this paper by Brezis](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2003-16-02/S0894-0347-02-00411-3/S0894-0347-02-00411-3.pdf) might help.

Comment: Indeed thanks to that paper I noticed that this equation sometimes doesn't have a solution in $W^{1,1} $ when $g^2 \in L^1$ and lead me to ask whether  with this new condition the answer is different.

Comment: Since $g^2$ is non-negative, doesn't zero mean value imply that $g=0$?